# Upload a file to a folder in MS teams channel

Tags: python, microsoft-teams

I have a simple .txt file and I would like to upload it to a folder created inside a MS teams channel using the pymsteams library or any other. What are the steps I should  follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Microsoft Graph API to achieve this. Microsoft Teams is ultimately using SharePoint behind the scenes for the Files section within Teams Channels.

Here's a lot of reading for you on the topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Understand this, and you'll be able to upload your file programmatically in no time.

Top tip. SharePoint permissions can be a nightmare... so make sure you have the right permissions in the place where you are trying to upload to.